# using multiple interface to access internet (eth0 and eth1 ...)

Tags: linux, routing, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

I used a tool named [WSLAttachSwitch] (https://github.com/dantmnf/WSLAttachSwitch) that attach a external Hyper-V switch to WSL2, because Windows do not expose every Windows network interface to WSL2.
Once the tool used a new interface is created named : eth1 and I used dhclient to give an ip to this interface :

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1488
        inet 172.30.20.144  netmask 255.255.240.0  broadcast 172.30.31.255
        inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fe28:f770  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:15:5d:28:f7:70  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 17  bytes 2593 (2.5 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 15  bytes 1174 (1.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.8  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fe01:2520  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:15:5d:01:25:20  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 11  bytes 2815 (2.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 10  bytes 1884 (1.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

The problem is that I want to be able to use both interface. When I want to ping 8.8.8.8 using eth1 (or to use this interface for another purpose) but it says that the destination is unreachable. I know it is a route problem but I have no clue on how to solve the problem.

here is also some information about route:

```
ip route show
default via 172.30.16.1 dev eth0 proto kernel
172.30.16.0/20 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 172.30.20.144
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.8
```

```
ip rule show
0:      from all lookup local
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

**UPDATE**
When I use the IP address of the interface it work :

```
ping -I 192.168.1.8 1.1.1.1
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) from 192.168.1.8 : 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=106 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=19.6 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=56 time=19.0 ms
```

Comment: do you intend to use both interfaces to reach the same destination simultaneously? right now, your route table will send any traffic destined for 8.8.8.8 through eth0 (because its your default route, and you don't have a more specific route to that destination). also where did this 1.1.1.1 interface come into the picture (its not in any of your command outputs). While you can use PING on a specific interface (for troubleshooting/diagnostics) you will not be able to do that with other applications. all traffic to destination X will pass through the same interface.

Comment: Yes I plan to use the same destination, I want to use these interface to enable MPTCP

Comment: from what I've been able to determine about multipath TCP, it impacts only the TCP layer, and does not provide a means to change the way IP traffic is routed by a single system. as such you cannot have multiple active IP-layer routes going out different interfaces. your system will send all traffic to a given destination out the same interface. if you want traffic to use multiple gateways, you will need hardware upstream to load-balance the traffic across the multiple gateways.